# global $post variable is always overwritten in single-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display 3 related product on single page in tabs. I have made a custom custom query like this:

```
$postid = array(1,2,3);

$args = array(
  'post_type'         => 'product',
  'post_status'       =>  'publish',
  'post__in'          =>  array_column($postid, 'ID'),

);

$loop = new WP_QUERY($args);
```

This query works and executes 3 times as well. But in loop I call a another template

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-meta-side' );
```

In content-single-product-meta-side.php the $post variable is reset and returns only the original query post variable.

```
global $product, $post;
echo $post_id = get_the_ID(); // old/original post id returns
```

I also tried to `setup_postdata( $post );` just after while loop but nothing happens.

Any ideas whats going wrong. 
Another query how do I setup the global $product variable.

Comment: typically you would use `global` to reference a variable that has been declared outside of a function from within the function. It does not, in itself, mean that a variable declared using `global` will be global.

Comment: I also tried to put the global on top of page before all functions. but nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`wc_get_template_part`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_template_part/) uses [`load_template`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/load_template/). This last, requires the template file with some global variables available to ensure that the WordPress environment is available from within the function:

```
global $posts, $post, $wp_did_header, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $wp_version, $wp, $id, $comment, $user_ID;
```

So, either you use the above global variables, or you can locate the file and include it in your scope:

```
include(locate_template('single-product-meta-side.php'));//Don't forget to set the right path for your file.
```

I hope this will help you.